# Cell color partially overriding cell border

Tags: tables, color

I am using `\cellcolor` to give a background to some cells. The cell color is partially coming over the border of the cell as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

This is my LaTeX code for the table.

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l}
\hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47.5\% (52.5\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{37.4\% (41.3\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{26.8\% (29.6\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{70.9\% (74.3\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{61.5\% (68.2\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{51.4\% (57.5\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72.1\% (76.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{65.4\% (69.8\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{54.7\% (59.8\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\cellcolor[gray]{.9}}72.1\% (77.1\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62.6\% (67.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{52.5\% (55.9\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{70.9\% (76.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{60.3\% (65.4\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{51.4\% (54.2\%)} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: What does it look like when you zoom into the apparent overlap? Does it go away?

Comment: yes it does go away, but it ain't nice when you see it at 100%

Comment: Readers tend to render the output based on the zoom-level. And, these renderings are pixel-based. In some instances, the lines (horizontal or vertical) could disappear. That's just how it is. And it may differ from one reader to another.

Comment: Please always post complete documents (not just fragments) If I try your document It works with xpdf and acrobat reader, but some of viewers have problems with such constructs. As described in the color package documentation you can try increasing the length `\arrayrulewidth` to make it less likely they get dropped. (perhaps its just your test example, but why use multicolumn on every entry?) Also, but unrelated never use `[h]` use at least `[ht]`

Comment: I use multicolumn on every entry because I don't manage to center align the cells in any other way. Do you know how I can do this without multicolumn?

Comment: Think I just figured out how by turning the { l l l l} into {c c c c}. Sorry I'm still confused about Latex tables.

Answer (score 8):

For the record, I still wasn't happy with this since I wanted the table to appear well in any viewer. So I sort of went round the problem by using `\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}[9pt]}c|}{72.1\% (77.1\%)}`

So the full code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l}
\hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47.5\% (52.5\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{37.4\% (41.3\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{26.8\% (29.6\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{70.9\% (74.3\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{61.5\% (68.2\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{51.4\% (57.5\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{72.1\% (76.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{65.4\% (69.8\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{54.7\% (59.8\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}[9pt]}c|}{72.1\% (77.1\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{62.6\% (67.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{52.5\% (55.9\%)} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{70.9\% (76.0\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{60.3\% (65.4\%)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{51.4\% (54.2\%)} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

to achieve this: [image]

I'm happy with the result. Maybe it would be useful to someone else.